Flink Histogram metric errors running multiple TaskManager
we are running 2 taskmanager and each taskmanager running with 2 slots. Operator parallelism we defined as 2.
source -> map -> sink
We have a histogram metric to compute the operator latency. Map operator is passed through and the execution time of operation is 0 or 1 millisec.
When we run with 1 taskmanager then the map operator histogram metric shows the correct value of 1 millisec.
But when we run with 2 taskmanager the map operator histogram metrics shows incorrect value in thousands. In the logs we verified the timings in 1 and 0 millisecs.
Example:
code
private transient Map<String, Counter> counters;
private transient Map<String, MetricGroup> metricGroups;
private transient Map<String, Histogram> histograms;
private transient MetricGroup metricGroup;
private transient MetricGroup getMetricGroup;
private  transient DropwizardHistogramWrapper dropwizardHistogramWrapper;

@Override
    public void open(Configuration config) {

        dropwizardHistogram = new com.codahale.metrics.Histogram(new UniformReservoir());
        dropwizardHistogramWrapper = new DropwizardHistogramWrapper(dropwizardHistogram);
        counters =new HashMap<>();
        metricGroups = new HashMap<>();
        histograms = new HashMap<>();

        this.metricGroup = getRuntimeContext().getMetricGroup()
                .addGroup(appNameKey, appConstant.getAppMetricGroup())
                .addGroup(domainNameKey, appConstant.getDomainName());

        this.nullRecordExceptionCounter = metricGroup.counter(DATAREME_FLINK_MULTI_TOPIC_NULL_RECORD_EXCEPTION);
        this.dataTransformer.open(config, getRuntimeContext());
    }


private void registerMetricGroup(){

        this.getMetricGroup=metricGroups.computeIfAbsent(key, k -> this.metricGroup.addGroup("SUB_TENANT_ID", bar).addGroup("TENANT_ID", foo));

        counters.computeIfAbsent(key+"_"+ DATAREME_FLINK_MULTI_TOPIC_INCOMING_RECORD_COUNTER, k -> this.getMetricGroup.counter(DATAREME_FLINK_MULTI_TOPIC_INCOMING_RECORD_COUNTER));   
        
        histograms.computeIfAbsent(key+"_"+ DATAREME_FLINK_MULTI_TOPIC_MESSAGE_LATENCY_HISTOGRAM, k -> this.getMetricGroup.histogram(DATAREME_FLINK_MULTI_TOPIC_MESSAGE_LATENCY_HISTOGRAM, dropwizardHistogramWrapper));

}

@Override
    public void flatMap(KafkaConsumerRecord consumerRecord, Collector<KafkaProducerRecord> collectorObject)
            throws Exception {
        long operatorStartTime = Instant.now().toEpochMilli();
    
        long operatorExecutionTime = Instant.now().toEpochMilli() - operatorStartTime;
        logger.info("***************operatorExecutionTime**************** {}", operatorExecutionTime);

        histograms.get(key+"_"+DATAREME_FLINK_MULTI_TOPIC_OPERATOR_LATENCY_HISTOGRAM).update(operatorExecutionTime);

    }



